# In Django what does the request argument in a method do?

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I have seen a few codes where sometimes the **authenticate method** have the **request argument** while other times it does not, e.g. see the below codes:

**Code 1:**

```
def register(request):
     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # code for automatic login after singing up
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
```

**Code 2:**

```
def login(request):
     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

According to the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend):

> `request` is an HttpRequest and maybe None if it wasn’t provided to
> `authenticate()` (which passes it on to the backend).

**What does this `request` argument actually do and when should I consider passing it in the `authenticate` method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Django docs, and confirmed by me just now looking at the source, this is passed to the `authenticate` method of whatever authentication backend you are using.

The only backend class that seems to use it is the `RemoteUserBackend`, and the reason for this is because RemoteUserBackend will create a local User model instance the first time a user (who already exists in the remote auth database) logs in, and then, before returning the user instance, the backend calls its own `configure_user` method, passing the new user instance, along with `request`.

Docs for that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend

But, here's where it gets silly.. is that, the default implementation of `configure_user` doesn't actually do anything, it's just a stub that you can extend in a subclass of `RemoteUserBackend` that you may choose to write if you want to add your own behavior to it.

Clear as mud.  But really it makes sense.  Perhaps some parameters were passed in the request that triggered the need for authentication, and some of those parameters contain information about the user that needs be stored in the newly created User instance...  The request object contains everything known about the request, it comes in handy.

Suffice to say that somebody, some time, either wrote an auth backend that required access to the request at this point, or the author of the auth module anticipated that someone might need it some day.  But in the auth module itself, by default, `request` is not used for anything that I can see.

So it doesn't seem necessary to pass `request` to `authenticate`, but if you can imagine that in the future you might want to configure your application with a funky authentication backend, you might want to pass it.. just in case it's needed by that backend.  The default `ModelBackend` doesn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The context for your question is that django is a web server.  In the classic HTTP/1 world, django receives a request and returns a response.  The **`request`** argument typically represents the http request that is sent from the user's browser to the server to which django will be responding.

So, in the first function in your code, **`register`** appears to be intended to be used as part of a view to register a new user.  The request, in this case, is useful to allow the register function to access the values that were entered in by the user in registering that user with the website.  The same goes for login.  The only specific reason that these function accept a request is that it allows the function to evaluate and take some action with respect to the information that the user submitted in the request.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Actually, I was not talking about the request argument passed to the `register` or login functions of my views.py. I am confused regarding the `request` being passed in the `authenticate` or `login` method i.e. in `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)` or the `login(request, user)`, why do we need the `request` argument, when we are explicitly passing the data (i.e. `username` and `passwords`), to those methods? I hope I make some sense.